# Gradle project refresh failed, Error: Cause: invalid address family type

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I run OpenSUSE v 13.1 32-bit and recently installed Android Studio v 0.8.6 (updated to v 0.8.9). If I remember correctly, it comes with Gradle v 1.12.

When I'm trying to create a new project as soon as I click the magic Finish button the IDE does it's thing and creates the project with Gradle instantly throwing an error:

> Gradle project refresh failed, Error: Cause: invalid address family type.

I have already tried searching it online, including these forums, and so far came across nothing. I have posed the same question on Gradle forums but apart from two other poor souls, that have the same problem, nobody suggested any solutions so far.

Answer (score 1):

set JAVA_HOME var to Oracle Java, from

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle-project-refresh-faild-error-cause-invalid-address-family-type

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, setting the $JAVA_HOME as described above didn't solve my problem.

My solution was to delete the $HOME/.gradle directory

After doing this Android-Studio installs gradle and configures it again and it worked :-)